# Gstat outputs NULL when using variogram() function

Tags: r, null, gstat, variogram

I am trying to do a kriging interpolation on a fake data set to familiarize myself with gstat. This code has worked before on a larger df but for some reason when I try to make the variogram, the output is empty, and I get a NULL error message. I've tried getting rid of the log() part and that did not help.

```
x <- c(42.500, 42.514, 42.500,42.507 , 42.500, 42.514)
y <-  c(-72.164, -72.164,  -72.171, -72.171, -72.178, -72.178 )
rs <-  c(3.24556,4.846672,6.456627,1.0056,3.222242,0.65788 )

fake_sub <- data.frame(x,y,rs)
coordinates(fake_sub) <- ~ x+y

sub_var <- variogram(log(rs)~1, fake_sub)
```

Comment: Can you show the error message you're getting? Often times the exact error message (including any error codes) can be helpful in diagnosing what's going wrong.

Comment: No error message comes up it juts makes an empty df unfortunately.